# Sql server 2014: backup log to 2 destinations

Tags: sql-server

We want a single job to back up log to azure and file system every time.

So we can log ship from file system and from azure at the same time.

I seem to recall that the redgate sql backup tool has a "backup and copy to..." feature. In sql natively yet?

Can this be done?

Comment: Uh, [`BACKUP...MIRROR TO...`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx)?

Comment: Are you referring to the [Azure blob storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449496(v=sql.120).aspx?)

Comment: Yes, i have backup to azure blob working well.

Comment: Mirror is only in enterprise...i am on standard...

Comment: So you're asking for a different native feature that does the same thing but doesn't require Enterprise Edition?

Comment: We dont have enterprise, and it seems crazy to use a 3rd party tool (redgate) to get the same bits in two spots.

Comment: Also, from docs, not clear if mirror can do two diff destination types. Docs imply that all mirrors must be same type.

Comment: People who can't use `MIRROR TO` usually just use PowerShell, batch files or tools like RoboCopy to push the files to a second location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, it seems, is plan to spend 1-10 days writing powershell scripts and building it yourself. (The multi day plan is because you will want to have logging, logging clean up, alerting, and everything else built.)

There was an article of a proof of concept using Azure for log shipping ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn606287.aspx ) but it appears MS pulled the post.

For many areas of SQL Server (such as index maint) there are widely used, de facto standard, scripts that are used by dbas (e.g. https://ola.hallengren.com/ ). For log shipping, there are pieces here and there, but there seems to be "touchstone" kits.

IOW: We are all on our own to improvise. Everything can be done. But neither MS nor anyone else has cleared a road through the forest.

Pack a spare machete, plenty of fresh water, and cliff bars. You are on your own.

Comment: I don't know that it would take 10 days to write a PowerShell Script for this...

Comment: "You are on your own." that's the worst outlook and view of this community that I have ever seen.  One thing I've learned is that we are never just "on our own".  The DBA community is so tight-knit and willing to help each other, it's incredible.

Comment: @Zane It is not 10 days to write a powershell script. It is multi days of development to re-create the log shipping mechanism, with history tracking monitor-ability, healing for all the little issues that happen moving files to S3 or azure, etc. E.g. to make a system that is robust and useful in a production environment.

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer I agree. The SQL Server community is amazing. Maybe it is out there, but I have beat a lot of bushes, and have not found a widely used community source replacement for the built in log shipping. I was hoping to find a powershell or similar replacement to the exe used by native log shipping. Such a kit would let me extend the mechanism for moving the files.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used SSIS to use the backup task so I'm not sure exactly how great this solution is however it should theoretically work and it took me about 10 minutes instead of 10 days.

First off create a package and make your backup database task. Set it up however you need to set it up like this.

[image: CryBaby1]

Then make a for each file loop and have it search through the directory you're adding it to.

[image: CryBaby2]

Map the results to a variable.

[image: Crybaby3]

Then use file System tasks to move it wherever the hell you want.

[image: DoneAndDone]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How do you use a file system task to push to azure blob storage or S3?